# Testing Netty client server with Awaitility?

Tags: netty, awaitility

Has anyone tried to use **Awaitility** to test a **Netty** Client and Server.

I want to test that the server has received all messages from the Client and any other tests that might be useful.

I suppose the only thing is how to get the number of messages the Server received from the Server side Handler

Answer (score 1):

I never use "Awaitility" to test netty, but writing such a test is really straight forward. Just add a custom SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler that increment a counter on every messageReceived(..) call and then check if the count match what you expect with junit assertEquals(..)

Comment: Hi Norman,
Whats the best way to then get the SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler used by the Client in the test ?
My setUp method instantiates and starts the Server. Is there a way to get the specific test Client's Handler from the ServerBootstrap?

Comment: Well you could just assign the SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler in the setUp() and store it in a private field. Then you can access it in your unit tests.

Comment: This is a full end-to-end regression test for the Client and Server.
So what I did in the end is add the following to my server class to return the handler: <br/> `MyMessageHandler handler = channelPipelineFactory.getPipeline().get(MyMessageHandler.class);` <br/> It's not nice but only wait I could think of getting the Server upstream handler to test the Client messages were received.